# How to pass only selected checkbox values from view to the controller in Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, session, model-view-controller, checkbox

[image]  I want to pass the only selected checkbox values  to the controller and retrieve only select values but the output is not coming until i select all the checkbox.

[image]

Comment: this all is done in the session

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152127/how-to-pass-checkbox-values-to-the-controller-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Refer above link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass checkbox values to the controller in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152127/how-to-pass-checkbox-values-to-the-controller-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: hi pradeep thank you  but i want to pass the only selected checkbox value

Comment: Can you provide a slimmed down example of what you have tried so far and the results you are looking for?

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.